# Position absolute or something else?

Tags: html, css, position

Hi I want to achieve the following:

The following code works but I'm not sure if **position: absolute** for left upper "Name" is the wise way to do it or should I use **float** ?

[image]
Here is the **html**

```
    <div class="bodyframe">
        <div class="upperbodyframe">   
            <div id="leftupperbodyframe">Name</div>
            <div id="rightupperbodyframe">Name 2 Name 3</div>

        </div>
```

And the **css**

```
![.bodyframe {

}
.upperbodyframe{


}

#leftupperbodyframe{

   text-align:left;
   border: 1px solid ;
    position: absolute;
}
#rightupperbodyframe{
    text-align: right;

    }]
```

Comment: floating is the way to go here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would use floats here. there's really no reason for the position:absolute here as well.

```
.upperbodyframe {overflow:hidden} /* or div will collapse with only floated elements inside */
#leftupperbodyframe {float:left; border: 1px solid ;}
#rightupperbodyframe {float:right;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with two method.

First Method

```
.upperbodyframe{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
#leftupperbodyframe{
    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
}
#rightupperbodyframe{
    position: absolute;
    right:0px;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
 <div class="upperbodyframe">   
            <div id="leftupperbodyframe">Name</div>
            <div id="rightupperbodyframe">Name 2 Name 3</div>
        </div>
```

Second Method

```
.upperbodyframe{
    width:100%;
}
#leftupperbodyframe{
    float:left;
}
#rightupperbodyframe{
    float:right;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
 <div class="upperbodyframe">   
            <div id="leftupperbodyframe">Name</div>
            <div id="rightupperbodyframe">Name 2 Name 3</div>
        </div>
```

Thanks,Arun Krishnan